# Can't get my htaccess rewrite conditions working...

Tags: .htaccess

This is my rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^8wayrun\.com/calibur [NC,OR]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.8wayrun\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://8wayrun.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Its simple... http://www.8wayrun.com is forwarded to http://8wayrun.com... this part works perfectly fine. But the first line should also forward http://8wayrun.com/calibur to http://8wayrun.com... this part does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does it rewrite http://8wayrun.com/calibur to currently?

Comment: It doesn't rewrite it at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:

```
RedirectMatch ^/calibur(.*) http://www.8wayrun.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.8wayrun\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://8wayrun.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```